Geometry of prym locus
The celebrated solution to the Schottky problem provides a beautiful geometric characterization of Jacobians among all principally polarized abelian varieties (ppavs). One might hope for a similarly elegant description of the locus of Prym varieties, but many mysteries remain.
Recall that to a double cover $f:C\rightarrow C'$ of curves one associates the Prym variety $P(f)=(P,\Xi)$, which is the ppav given by the connected component of the identity in the kernel of the norm map $f_*:JC\rightarrow JC'$, endowed with the principal polarization coming from the restriction of the canonical polarization of $JC$. When the double cover is ramified at two points, then $C$ and $C'$ have genus $g$ and $g-1$ for some $g$, and this gives a map from the moduli space $R_{g,2}$ of such covers to the space $A_g$ of $g$-dimensional principally polarized abelian varieties.
Let $\mathcal{P}_{g-1} \subset \mathcal{A}_{g-1}$ be the closure of the image of the Prym map:
$$ \begin{aligned}
P: \mathcal{R}_g &\longrightarrow \mathcal{A}_{g-1} \\
 (C,\eta) &\longmapsto P(C,\eta).
 \end{aligned}$$
where $(C,\eta)$ represents a genus $g$ curve with a 2-torsion line bundle $\eta$ (defining a double cover) and $\mathcal{A}_{g-1}$ is the moduli space of $(g-1)$-dimensional ppavs. This leads to a series of fundamental, but surprisingly open, questions:
What can one say about the geometry of  $\mathcal{P}_{g-1}$ and the Prym map, beyond the well-understood case of unramified double covers?  Specifically, what is the dimension of $\mathcal{P}_{g-1}$?  What are its singularities, and how do these relate to special Prym varieties? Can we compute invariants like the Kodaira dimension of $\mathcal{P}_{g-1}$ or study its intersection theory within  $\mathcal{A}_{g-1}$?
I know that the dimension of $\mathcal{P}_{g-1}$ is known to be $3g-3$ for $g \geq 5$. This follows from the fact that the moduli space $\mathcal{R}_g$ of double covers has dimension $3g-3$, and for $g \geq 5$, the Prym map is generically injective. For lower genus, the situation is different. For $g=2$, $\mathcal{P}_1$ is just a point (the jacobian of an elliptic curve). For $g=3$, $\mathcal{P}_2$ has dimension 3 and is isomorphic to the moduli space of plane quartics. For $g=4$, $\mathcal{P}_3$ has dimension 9 and is a divisor in $\mathcal{A}_3$.

"Beyond the well-understood case of unramified double covers": what do you mean? It seems that you are precisely asking about this case.
